# R: Create a flag that is 0 or 1 for a whole group if one value in that group is below a certain threshold

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
group  services
1         75
1         105
1         110
2         110
2         110
2         110
```

I want to create a flag where if any of the group service values fall below 100, it is flagged 0. If they are all above 100, it is flagged 1.
Output would be:

```
group    services      flag
1         75            0
1         105           0
1         110           0
2         110           1
2         110           1
2         110           1
```

The dataset is thousands of groups long, so I'm not sure how to do this. I tried using dplyr 
as

```
 dataset%>%
       group_by_(group)%>%
       mutate(flag:= services>=100)
```

I tried searching, but couldn't find an answer as to how to get the flag to apply to a whole group for a large dataset with lots of groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` approach

```
transform(df1, flag = ave(services, group, FUN = function(x) all(x >= 100)))
#  group services flag
#1     1       75    0
#2     1      105    0
#3     1      110    0
#4     2      110    1
#5     2      110    1
#6     2      110    1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include an `any` condition in your test, to return `TRUE` (or 1) if any value in your group is inferior to 100.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(flag = as.numeric(!any(services<100)))

#  A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group services  flag
  <int>    <int> <dbl>
1     1       75     0
2     1      105     0
3     1      110     0
4     2      110     1
5     2      110     1
6     2      110     1
```

Comment: Actually, it's `!any(services<100))`. Upvote but edit it.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at this, but how would I make sure the flag column gets added? I'm receiving an error column that flag is unknown or uninitialized.

Comment: In order to include the changes into your dataframe, you need to assign it: `data <- data %>% ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, flag := +(all(services >= 100)), group]
df1
#   group services flag
#1:     1       75    0
#2:     1      105    0
#3:     1      110    0
#4:     2      110    1
#5:     2      110    1
#6:     2      110    1
```